# JOLT Specification to remove the root element from input json

Tags: json, jolt

I have following input JSON request :

```json
{
  "RootElement": [
    {
      "External_Contact_ID": "6504668",
      "Email_Address": "test@gmail.com",
      "First_Name": "Test_Name",
      "Last_Name": "TestLastName",
      "Member_STATUS": "ACTIVE"
    },
    {
      "External_Contact_ID": "6506709",
      "Email_Address": "test1@gmail.com",
      "First_Name": "Test_Name1",
      "Last_Name": "TestLastName1",
      "Member_STATUS": "ACTIVE"
    }
  ]
}
```

want to remove the root element from the input JSON and transform it into below format :

```json
[
  {
    "External_Contact_ID": "6504668",
    "Email_Address": "test@gmail.com",
    "First_Name": "Test_Name",
    "Last_Name": "TestLastName",
    "Member_STATUS": "ACTIVE"
  },
  {
    "External_Contact_ID": "6506709",
    "Email_Address": "test1@gmail.com",
    "First_Name": "Test_Name1",
    "Last_Name": "TestLastName1",
    "Member_STATUS": "ACTIVE"
  }
]
```

Can you please help me with JOLT specification ?

Comment: Can you check out the shortest one provided as the second answer please

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below Jolt Spec.

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "RootElement": {
        "*": "[]"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Thanks Bhavna,,,getting output as expected.

Comment: Nice to help you @Nitinamg

Answer (score 0):

You can shortly apply the following shift transformation :

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "" // the asterisk stands for the "RootElement"
    }
  }
]
```